# why .gradle file is not build in library android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

**Link Lib**

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3143

I  m trying to use  this library in my app but the problem is that
     `.gradle` is not build in this library so I can't use this  library in my app.

Comment: The instructions are given on the library page itself. You don't need the .gradle file

Comment: did you try to add `compile 'com.azeesoft.lib.colorpicker:colorpicker:1.0.8@aar'`  in your app's build.gradle? try to look at this page [AndroidPhotoshopColorPicker](https://github.com/AzeeSoft/AndroidPhotoshopColorPicker)

Comment: have you add maven to build gradle